# How to check if the function with parameter returns true or not

Tags: php, mysql

here i am trying to check if condition with if `function($String) == true` if function returns true if returns true else `header('Location: home.php')` 
I am checking the if condition in the page but i am not able to see any statement or page redirect.

what may be the problem?

Here is what i have done.

```
<?php 
      if(ifproductPublished($qs) == true){
        echo "hey its true";
      } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
      }
?>
```

Function:

```
function ifproductPublished($productID){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_status FROM product_list WHERE product_id='$productID'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
        $product_status = $row["product_status"];                       
        if($product_status == 1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }       
        } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Your function must only `return TRUE;` or `return FALSE;` to do what you want.

Comment: You return on the first pass. Put `product_status = 1` into your query then you'll only get a result if it was published. Also use prepared statements this is open to SQL injections. You also will only get a response if there is a record. You need to do something when no record is present, (row count 0).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @chris85, you could alter the sql and then simplify the function like:

```
function ifproductPublished( $productID ){
    $conn = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
    if ( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    $sql = "SELECT `product_status` FROM `product_list` WHERE `product_id`='$productID' and `product_status`=1;";
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    $status = false;

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {                       
        $status=true;
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close();
    return $status;
}
```